# convert mongo bash $or command to php

Tags: php, mongodb

How do I convert {"ID": 1, $or : [ { 'Age': '0' } , { 'Age' : 0 } ] } to a PHP command.
I tried (array('ID' => 1, array( '$or' => array( array('Age' => 0),array('Age' => '0'))))

But did not get the correct results. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you just want:

```
$json = '<your string>';
$result = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: That worked great!!! I has missed quotes around $or, that was causing the problems. Thanks